# Error: Compile Error: Invalid foreign key relationship: Advance_Milestone__c.FFS_Milestone__c at line 28 column 44

Tags: apex

Folks am getting this error - Basically want to update the

( parent object - Advance_Milestone__c - custom fields ) based on the values of

the custom fields in its child (FFS_Milestone__c).

PS - have given the same names to the custom fields in the child. Can someone help. This is the code

```
Public class NewAMTPAIDDDUEUpdate {
    public static void NewMileApUpdate(Advance_Milestone__c [] AM ) {
        for (Advance_Milestone__c  o : AM ) {

            // o.Amount_Paid__c = 0 ;


           // Updating Amount Due and Amount Paid in Advance Milestone after creation of FFS Milestone records

           List <Advance_Milestone__c> A  = [Select Id, Current_Milestone__c, Amount_Due__c , Amount_Paid__c , (Select FFS_Milestone__c.Current_Milestone__c, FFS_Milestone__c.Amount_Paid__c ,FFS_Milestone__c.Total_Receivable__c  from Advance_Milestone__c.FFSs_Milestone__r )  from Advance_Milestone__c ]; 

           for (Advance_Milestone__c CA : A) {

               // (currentA.FFSs_Milestone__r.Current_Milestone__c == 'FFS') && 
               if ((CA.Current_Milestone__c == 'FFS') && (CA.FFS_Milestone__c.Amount_Paid__c > CA.Advance_Milestone_Amt__c)) {
                   CA.Amount_Paid__c = CA.Advance_Milestone_Amt__c ;
               }

               CA.Amount_Due__c = CA.Advance_Milestone_Amt__c - CA.Amount_Paid__c ;

               Update CA.Amount_Due__c ;
               Update CA.Amount_Paid__c ;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your Adavanced_Miilestone__c record have only one FFS_Milestone__c child?

Comment: Yes Advance_Milestone_c has only one child FFS_Milestone_c. Advance. Advance_Milestone__c has a lookup in turn to Project_Milestone__c. Current Milestone field of of Both Advance as well FFS change based on the change and edit in the Project_Milestone__c

Comment: Did you try the new code with your logic?

Comment: Yes - thanks the new  code has compiled well . One query -  List <Advance_Milestone__c> milestonesToUpdate = new List <Advance_Milestone__c>();  - Is the new list statement required - cant we directly update Advance_Milestone__c . Also do I use an after insert trigger with this code since it uses and updates an existing record

Answer (score 0):

1) In your query, you are querying out all the Advance_Milestone__c records. Do you really need all of them? 
2) Don't put queries and DML statements in for loops

And your error is quite descriptive on where you have gone wrong.

```
CA.FFS_Milestone__c.Amount_Paid__c
```

It should rather be

```
//assuming there is only one child for Advanced_Milestone__c
CA.FFS_Milestone__r.get(0).Amount_Paid__c
```

Here is an example code (might not achieve what you want exactly because you are missing information in the question)

```
Public class NewAMTPAIDDDUEUpdate {
    public static void NewMileApUpdate(Advance_Milestone__c [] AM ) {

        List<Id> amIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Advance_Milestone__c  o : AM ) {
            amIds.add(o.Id);
        }

       // Updating Amount Due and Amount Paid in Advance Milestone after creation of FFS Milestone records

       List <Advance_Milestone__c> A  = [Select Id, Current_Milestone__c, Amount_Due__c , Amount_Paid__c , (Select Current_Milestone__c, Amount_Paid__c , Total_Receivable__c  from FFS_Milestone__r )  from Advance_Milestone__c Where Id IN :amIds]; 

       List <Advance_Milestone__c> milestonesToUpdate = new List <Advance_Milestone__c>();

       for (Advance_Milestone__c CA : A) {
           if(CA.FFS_Milestone__r != null && CA.FFS_Milestone__r.size() > 0) {
               //assuming there is only one child FFS_Milestone__c for each Advanced_Milestone__c
               FFS_Milestone__c ffs = CA.FFS_Milestone__r.get(0);

               //place your logic here

               milestonesToUpdate.add(CA);

           }

        }
        update milestonesToUpdate;

    }
}
```

Comment: Just returned and trying your new code - one question -why the second list statement - List <Advance_Milestone__c> milestonesToUpdate = new List <Advance_Milestone__c>();  Cant you directly update Advance_Milestone__c with the new values of FFS_Milestone__c

Comment: Also once this compiles - do I run this using After Insert trigger - since this method is using an existing value of child record in FFS_Milestone_c to update the value of parent custom fields in Advance_Milestone__c

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark as the answer.
As for your first question, yes you do need that list. It is never a good idea to have DML or SOQL statements inside for loops, because you can quickly reach the govenor limits. Instead you collect the records to be updated in a list and update them as a list.
Second question, do you want this to be a trigger? then it should be a before insert trigger without the update statements. You can't update the triggering record in an After insert trigger